# Text at the end of the table

Tags: tables, landscape

I am experiencing another problem with my table I would like to include a long note at the end of the table. 
The code I wrote is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.1cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.0cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\footnotesize{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{\textbf{Subjective Freedom and Preferences for Redistribution - Alternative Instruments}\label{table8}} 
\begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}}
\hline\hline 
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Fst Stage}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Snd Stage}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{LL}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\rho$=0}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Obs.}}\smallskip \\
 &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First Lag SF}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second Lag SF}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Settler}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Genetic}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{SF}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fairness}}& & &\\
 &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(Country Average)}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(Country Average)}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Mortality}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Distance}}&& &&&\\
\hline \noalign{\medskip}
1. Using second lag of SF &0.017***&0.013**{\textcolor{white}{*}}& & &0.010***&0.188***&-46,770.27&-0.071***&98,673 \medskip \\
2. Using rate of settler mortality &0.071***& &-0.018***&  &0.010***&0.180***&-50,073.15&-0.035***&98,673 \medskip \\ 
3. Using genetic distance &0.083***& &-0.016***&-0.051*** &0.010***&0.181***&-49,175.98 
&-0.038***&98,673 \medskip \\
4. Using latitude &0.003*{\textcolor{white}{**}}& & & &0.010***&0.208***&-65,841.53 
&-0.073***&98,673 \medskip \\
5. Endogenous SF &0.015***& & & &0.010***&0.208***&-210,549.47  
&-0.068***&98,673 \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\footnotesize Notes: ***, ** and * denote significance at 1\%, 5\% and 10\%, respectively. In model 1, we include the second lag of subjective freedom as a country average. In model, reported in row 2, we add the log of settler mortality to the first lag of subjective freedom. In model 3, we augment model 2, by adding the log of genetic distance. In this case, we use US as reference country. In model reported in row 4 we drop the continent dummy and we include the (log) of latitude, measured as the distance of capital city to the Equator. Finally, in model 5 we endogeneize subjective freedom using the lag of average SF in a country. }\\
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

The main problem is that the text does non follow the end of the table, but it is incredibly longer. Is there any way I can write a footnote, which stays within the width of the table.

Comment: It's not the footnote's fault. Your table goes beyond the page limit, and the footnote, of course, follows. Why are you setting the margins using `\newcommand`s?

Comment: Because i wanted to fit the table in one page using a font size that was at least footnotesize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have partially re-done your table to fit a page in portrait mode, using `tabularx` which `X` columns take all the available space; note the starting command that allows this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{...}
```

You can fill the remaining content. The notes below have been added as regular text, but I don't think this should give you any issues. If there are, feel free to comment.

Also, remember to use the `geometry` package to set the margins.

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\bfseries\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\bfseries\arraybackslash}m{5mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\footnotesize
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1cm}
\centering
\caption{\bfseries Subjective Freedom and Preferences for Redistribution  Alternative Instruments}
\label{table8}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CZYYYYY}
% header
\toprule
& & Using second lag of SF & Using rate of settler mortality & Using genetic distance & Using latitude & Endogenous SF \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{1st Stage}} & First Lag SF\newline\tiny{Country average} & & \\
    & Second Lag SF\newline\tiny{Country average} & & \\
    & Settler Mortality & & \\
    & Genetic Distance & & \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{2nd Stage}}    & SF & & \\
    & Fairness & & \\ \midrule
    & LL & & \\
    & $p=0$ & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{table}\noindent
{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses. \\
\textbf{Notes:} ***, ** and * denote significance at 1\%, 5\% and 10\%, respectively. In model 1, we include the second lag of subjective freedom as a country average. In model, reported in row 2, we add the log of settler mortality to the first lag of subjective freedom. In model 3, we augment model 2, by adding the log of genetic distance. In this case, we use US as reference country. In model reported in row 4 we drop the continent dummy and we include the (log) of latitude, measured as the distance of capital city to the Equator. Finally, in model 5 we endogeneize subjective freedom using the lag of average SF in a country.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Alenanno, thanks for your suggestion. It looks nice, although I need to keep the format I had previously to maintain consistency with the journal style. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dario No problem!

Answer (score 1):

I did it with the tools from my answer to your previous post. I added `threeparttable` for the table notes, and `siunitx` for the formatting and alignment of numbers in your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, makecell, threeparttable, siunitx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\captionsetup{font=bf}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, table-number-alignment =center}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.1cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.0cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \newcounter{rownum}\setcounter{rownum}{0}
  \setlength\defaultaddspace{1.25ex}
  %setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \centering\footnotesize
  \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
  %
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Subjective Freedom and Preferences for Redistribution – Alternative Instruments}\label{table8}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\refstepcounter{rownum}\eqmakebox[R][r]{\therownum.}\hskip\labelsep}lS S *{2}{S[table-format=-1.3]}*{2}{S}S[table-format=-6.2,table-space-text-post={}] S[table-format=-1.3] S[table-format=5.0, table-space-text-post={}]}
      \toprule\midrule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{First Stage}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Second Stage}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{LL}}& {\boldmath $\rho = 0$} &{\bfseries Obs.}\\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {\thead{First Lag SF & & & & & & & & \\(Country Average)}} &{ \thead{Second Lag SF\\(Country Average)}} & {\thead{Settler\\Mortality}} & {\thead{Genetic\\Distance}} & {\thead{SF}} & {\thead{Fairness}}& & &\\
      \cmidrule(lr){1-10}
      \addlinespace
      Using second lag of SF & 0.017*** & 0.013**{\textcolor{white}{*}} & & & 0.010*** & 0.188*** & -46 770.27 & -0.071*** & 98673 \medskip \\
      Using rate of settler mortality & 0.071*** & & -0.018*** & & 0.010*** & 0.180*** & -50073.15 & -0.035*** & 98673 \\
      \addlinespace
      Using genetic distance &0.083***& &-0.016***&-0.051*** &0.010***&0.181***&-49175.98
      &-0.038***&98673\\
      \addlinespace
      Using latitude &0.003*{\textcolor{white}{**}}& & & &0.010***&0.208***&-65841.53
      &-0.073***&98673\\
      \addlinespace
      Endogenous SF &0.015***& & & &0.010***&0.208***&-210549.47
      &-0.068***&98673 \\
      \midrule\bottomrule
      \addlinespace
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[]Notes: ***, ** and * denote significance at 1\,\%, 5\,\% and 10\,\%, respectively. In model 1, we include the second lag of subjective freedom as a country average. In model, reported in row 2, we add the log of settler mortality to the first lag of subjective freedom. In model 3, we augment model 2, by adding the log of genetic distance. In this case, we use US as reference country. In model reported in row 4 we drop the continent dummy and we include the (log) of latitude, measured as the distance of capital city to the Equator. Finally, in model 5 we endogeneize subjective freedom using the lag of average SF in a country.
      \item[] Standard errors in parentheses
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Bernard, thanks a lot for your kind help. It is exactly the format I needed. Best Dario